# "The controller for path '...' was not found or does not implement IController." triggers 500 instead of 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-routing

This MVC application will throw a HttpException if it cannot find a route.  This is fine, the exception has a 404 status code. However, when customErrors are setup under , for some reason, instead of following the 404 error, MVC treats this exception as a general unhandled exception and follows the 500 status code instead.

**Why do custom errors trigger a 500 handling, rather than the desired 404?**

The .NET Error Page configuration:

[image]

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) 
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your error pages are themselves generating errors, then IIS has to throw it's hands up and return a 500. It's hard to tell for sure from the screenshot, but it appears as if your error pages are redirecting to URLs without extensions, i.e. `Http400` rather than `Http400.html`. If there's no extension, then MVC will still try to serve the URL instead of IIS directly serving a static page, and if MVC can't find a controller to serve that URL, it throws a 404, which causes it to try to serve the 404 URL again, which it can't, so it throws a 404, etc. Eventually, it dies with a 500 because you've got an endless redirect.

You can have dynamic error pages, but you must be *very* careful, and ensure that they work correctly all the time. Otherwise, the safe bet is always on a static HTML file. If that's what you're doing already, then you just need to ensure that you redirect to the actual file with the extension.

Comment: I can indeed navigate directly to /mvcError/Http404 to see the page as normal. Additionally, if inside a controller I throw a new HttpNotFoundResult() (and custom errors is on), then I also see the desired custom 404 page (and not the ASP.NET yellow 404 page).